# Cost Value of Changing appliances that run on 240 down to 120

Tags: electrical-engineering, electrical

I have lived overseas for many years and purchased your standard appliances.  Anyway moving back to the US, I had to purchase transformers to bring the voltage down from 240V to 120V.  I know that there also issues with cycles (50cycles verse 60) but that not an issue yet.

So my question is I am trying to figure out the electrical cost of running these appliances so I can make a decision of when the return on investment is right to replace these appliances with ones that run off 120V.

i.e. I have a 3000W transformer that runs an appliance - which uses 900W for two heaters and 600W for a pump.  I am paying about \$0.06 per kW-hour.  A new appliance is about \$325.

I have about 6 240V various appliances so it could drop my electrical bill.

thanks

Comment: Measure the transformer's power draw when unloaded, or read its datasheet - or guess at comfortably under 100W. That's essentially the penalty you're paying for running your appliance through a transformer. So, 10 hours for \$0.06, or a week for \$1  Or 6 years 24/7/365 for \$325...

Comment: Unfortunately the data sheet is not very helpful.  But I will try to see if I can measure the power draw.

Comment: it might actually be economic to install 220 outlets.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would like to mention that you can find 240V outlets in the U.S. intended for residential use by electric stoves and dryers.

Second, it is sometimes possible to run a 240V appliance using 120V at the expense of cooking time (given that it is purely an analog device). For example, a 240V water kettle with a given resistance heating element will perform the same job using 120V, but at 1/4 power output. This means it will also take 4 times longer to boil the water.

Finally, its difficult to answer this question without knowing more details about the transformers and appliance loads. All transformers have some losses and its possible to calculate these if you have the parameters of the transformer. Otherwise, its best to approximate the efficiency of the transformer using the labeled rating (output power / input power). Some hardware tools like the kill-a-watt exist that may allow you to empirically determine the efficiency. I suggest you look into that to calculate the ROI of eliminating the transformers.

Comment: The heaters should be fine, but the pump will not be running optimally as the windings were designed for 50Hz, so you should look to replace that.

Comment: As to your first comment - transformer is plugged into a normal 120v outlet - I am not using any 240V outlets.                                                            These appliances run about 8hrs per day / 365 per year.  About 6hrs for the heaters (at 900 total watts) and about 1hr for the pump.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the exact loss factor of the transformer and how much you use the appliance. E.g let's just assume the loss factor is 50%  it's probably much much less that, but just see what happens. Let's assume you use the appliance 1 hour a day every day. Then you are paying about ${$}72$ a year to run the appliance and with out the transformer you'd be paying ${$}36$. So it would take about 10 years to pay back the investment. Probably not worth it. Now if you use the appliance 24 hours a day every day might be a different story.